# Integral over complex conjugate domain

Tags: complex-analysis

So I know that $e^{ikz},~z\in\mathbb{C}$ is analytic, so without any poles we have

$$\int_\gamma e^{ikz}dz=0$$ 
for any path $\gamma$. But what if the integration is taken over the conjugate domain, like
$$\int_{\gamma} e^{ikz}d\bar{z}?$$
Is it simple to come up with a residue theorem for this, or does one have to re-engineer Cauchy's theorem for every specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the conjugate there is essentially equivalent to applying it to the function; if $I(\gamma) = \int_{\gamma}f(z)\,d\overline{z}$, then $\overline{I(\gamma)} = \int_{\gamma}\overline{f(z)}\,dz$.

And the problem with that? It's strongly path-dependent. Unlike holomorphic functions, conjugate-holomorphic functions aren't exact forms. Let $f(x+iy)=g(x,y)+ih(x,y)$ and parametrize the closed loop $\gamma$ enclosing a region $R$ by $Z(t)=X(t)+iY(t)$ for $t$ from $a$ to $b$. We get
\begin{align*}I(\gamma) &= \int_a^b \left(g(X(t),Y(t))+ih(X(t),Y(t)\right)\cdot (X'(t)-iY'(t))\,dt\\
&= \int_a^b g(X,Y)X'(t) + h(X,Y)Y'(t) + ih(X,Y)X'(t)-ig(X,Y)Y'(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_{\gamma}(g+ih)(X,Y)\,dx + (h-ig)(X,Y)\,dy\\
I(\gamma) &= \iint_R \frac{\partial (h-ig)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (g+ih)}{\partial y}\,dx\,dy\\
&= \iint_R -if'(x+iy) - if'(x+iy)\,dx\,dy\end{align*}
(We abbreviate $g(X(t),Y(t))$ by $g(X,Y)$. These are all real double integrals and line integrals, although we allow complex-valued functions to simplify things a bit. The step from a line integral to an area integral was an application of Green's theorem.)

So then, the integral $\int_{\gamma} f(z)\,d\overline{z}$ is the area integral of $-2if'$ over the region enclosed. It's not something that we can focus on a few points to handle - we have to deal with the whole region. And that's for a function that doesn't have any singularities in there.